# no me llama el boton onClickListener en Android Studio

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio, login

Estoy creando un login pero no me reconoce cuando pulso el botón btnLogin no crea ninguna acción en el código ni siquiera me aparece habilitado el OnClickListener ni el ErrorListener este es mi código del Activity no se cual puede ser el problema necesito ayuda porfavor

```
package com.example.elena5;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Email, Pass;
    Button Logear;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Inicializamos
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
        Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        Logear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        Logear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ValidarEmail("http://192.168.1.4/index/Validarusuario.php");
            }
        });
    }
    private  void ValidarEmail(String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (!response.isEmpty()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.nombres, Email.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usuario o Contraseña Incorrectas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> Parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Parametros.put("email",Email.getText().toString());
                Parametros.put("password", Pass.getText().toString());
                return  Parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Este es mi código del XML donde esta mi el botón se supone que esta todo bien y lo estoy llamando correctamente soy nuevo en esto por lo que no entiendo cual puede ser el detalle en esta acción

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
                android:text="Iniciar Sesión"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```

no tiene ningun error el codigo lo estoy haciendo con una base de datos local.

Comment: me paso lo mismo, encontraste alguna solución??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de la version 8 de android por cuestión de seguridad te pide que coloques en el manifest la siguiente linea de codigo y listo.

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Y con esto se soluciono mi problema.